# Open a new console with every new Thread in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, console, console-application

I want to have a new console open whenever I create a new thread so that the output will be organized. My application is fully console based. Would this be possible if so how?

Regards!

Comment: Open a new console, pass it to the thread when you start it?

Comment: Can a process have more than one console?

Comment: I think you might have to create a standard window with a text box and direct the output there. I have a feeling that processes only have one console. Not sure if things are different in .net, but that's the state of play in Win32.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: you're right. I looked at [Console class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.aspx) expecting to see a `Console.Create` method, but there is none.

Comment: In my case, I have multiple consoles for every thread, I just want one.

Comment: I know, just run VS as administrator, there would be one console only.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`A process can be associated with only one console`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: That means he has to create multiple processes with one thread in each?

Comment: @DaeMoohn No that means he can not create multiple consoles in a single app.

Comment: That's an interesting limitation.

Answer (score 0):

It's not difficult to work around this limitation.

The code that you want to run as a separate thread with its own console window, simply code that as a separate console application, passing parameters as required on the command line.

Then run separate instances of this code using Start() inside your main application.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get this working replacing the TextWriter (Console.SetOut())
and storing the values into a ThreadLocal

Then when you get the values from your TextWriter they are per thread